# Save a variable file into a folder

Tags: file, variables, text, vbscript, directory

I think I managed to mess up my program. Here is the troubled locations.

```
name=inputbox("Type the name here.",,"")
Dim file : Set file = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If file.FileExists("G:\Rita\memory"\name) Then
msgbox("I believe we have met before.")
End If
```

then there is a bunch of dialogue and then these lines here.

```
Dim aData : aData = Array(name, age, color)
If file.FileExists(name) Then aData = Split(file.OpenTextFile("G:\Rita\memory"\name).ReadAll())
file.CreateTextFile("G:\Rita\memory"\name).Write Join(aData)
```

This program was written from flash drive. Anyway I and having a couple of small issues, the main one is that it will not save into the premade "memory" folder. another one (not as important) is that is does not save as a text file anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the "&" and your quote(") is in the wrong place on each line that has the variable name. I corrected that in your code. Try this.

```
name=inputbox("Type the name here.",,"")
Dim file : Set file = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If file.FileExists("G:\Rita\memory\" & name) Then
msgbox("I believe we have met before.")
End If

Dim aData : aData = Array(name, age, color)
If file.FileExists(name) Then aData = Split(file.OpenTextFile("G:\Rita\memory\" & name).ReadAll())
file.CreateTextFile("G:\Rita\memory\" & name).Write Join(aData)
```